# jQuery: process HTML in chunks

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've got a WebExtension that processes a site's HTML `body`, sending it to a backend which modifies some of the text, then replacing the old HTML with the backend's response. The problem is that this can take a little too long, so I'd like to process the text in reasonable chunks, say something like 3 paragraphs or 200 words at a time.

What's a good way to break up the HTML into those chunks, without breaking any elements etc.? It would be particularly cool if I could only ever process whatever the user is currently seeing on their screen.

PS: There's one solution I could think of, but it doesn't feel very elegant: Is it okay to do this by character offsets, say I know I'll be sending characters 0 to 1000 of the HTML to the backend first and replace them, then characters 1000+x to 2000+x where x is the difference in length between the original and updated HTML?

Comment: Select it using Dom selectors.

Comment: Do you mean you're just changing visible text, not the html elements themselves?

Comment: Tony, yes, I'm only changing the text, or to be more precise I introduce new markup (`span`s) around certain words, which allows for dynamically changing the text.

Answer (score 2):

> PS: There's one solution I could think of, but it doesn't feel very elegant: Is it okay to do this by character offsets, say I know I'll be sending characters 0 to 1000 of the HTML to the backend first and replace them, then characters 1000+x to 2000+x where x is the difference in length between the original and updated HTML?

From a technical perspective it'd be perfectly fine to do this, but it would be headache inducing to set it up without errors and earn some scrunched eyebrows in future code reviewing.

Only sending through what's currently visible would be relatively easy depending on how picky your needs are. You could try something like:

```
$('body:visible').each(function() {
    // Send $(this).html() to server
    console.log('HTML The user can see: '+$(this).html())
})
```

Though this may not be exactly what you're looking for, and you'd have the problem of knowing when and how often to trigger that function.

> Update: Expanding on making this more idea more powerful

## Getting current HTML and future HTML

This is more tricky, and varies with ease depending on how much you're willing to change infrastructure.

#### 1) Grab and isolate current elements

If you made everything divs (i.e. make `<img src="test.jpg" />` into `<div style="background-image:url(test.jpg)"></div>`), you could isolate each visible and invisible div much more easily:

```
var visibleHTML = '';
var invisibleHTML = '';
$('body div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        visibleHTML += $(this).html()
    } else {
        invisibleHTML += $(this).html()
    }
})
// Send visibleHTML and invisibleHTML separately to server
```

Problems with this approach is it would likely ignore script tags and other vital HTML that isn't detected by `.is(':visible')`, which *technically* could contribute to the "visible" experience, and the `visibleHTML` and `invisibleHTML` could be all out of sync at the end of the loop.

#### 2) Restructure the page entirely

This could be a pain to rewrite, but would make things ***much*** more modular and easy to throw around and break up by bits. Each html "chunk" would be a JS string on page load, as such.

```
var upperHTML =
'<div id="header">' +
    '<div id="header-content">This is part of the header</div>' +
    '<div id="header-content2">This is part of the header</div>' +
'</div>';

var middleHTML = 
'<div id="main-content">' +
    '<div id="inner-content">' +
        '<p>Hi, I\'m the main</p>' +
    '</div>'
'</div>';

var lowerHTML = 
'<div id="footer">' +
    '<div id="footer-content">' +
        '<p>What an awesome footer!</p>' +
    '</div>'
'</div>';
```

Obviously your strings would look much longer than that, and would be tedious to convert from HTML files because JS does not tolerate new lines within strings. (See: [unterminated string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)) This will force you to concatenate the strings with `'' + '' +` if you would like to visualize the new lines like I have done so above.

It would also be wise to split it up in more chunks than just 3 chunks like I did to be as modular and isolated as possible -- without giving you too much of a headache, of course.

You would also have to add `\` to escape from single quotes within your HTML itself.

I actually have used this method multiple times, it is sort of clunky at first, but makes for quite a robust development interface as you can grab and place html wherever you want (including sending it to a webserver, in your case) or within the document `$('#target-div').html(middleHTML);` You always know what `upperHTML` will look like, and hiding, showing, moving, or sending it somewhere is extremely fast as it is all already cached to memory as a string.

#### 3) Look into server caching, or different data format

I'm not exactly sure what your server is doing with these bits of HTML, but in reality, if the server is unable to handle HTML quickly there is likely a larger design issue at stake. Depending on what that server needs the html *for*, raises some important questions:

- Can this server not just receive JSON data and recreate the HTML itself based on limited variables passed through?
- Is the HTML extremely similar for every user? Can the server not cache a large bit of it?

This all sounds like a rather out-there use-case, which is why I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: Thanks ethancrist. Right, I suppose I could retrigger that function as soon as I notice a scroll event? Is there a clever way to select `body:visible` "plus some more", to already load the text for the next scroll?

Comment: Just added a mini-book to my comment to help give you some things to think about.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll give it some thought and try to see what's best.